# meaning of "call me an amenity" phrase

Tags: meaning, phrases, lyrics

This phrase is used in the lyrics of the song 'Bad Liar' by Selena Gomez. Thanks in advance.

Comment: questions about the meaning of song lyrics belong on https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @ab123, could you add the research that you have done to find the answer to this question?

Comment: @BhoomikaArora what do you mean? Can't I ask something I was doubtful of? I did a Google search, but was unsure, so asked.

Comment: @ab123: At ELU, it is appreciated if you provide some searches that you made to answer the question yourself. This prevents people from doing a simple google search and providing the same non-useful answers that you may have already read.

Comment: @BhoomikaArora oh ok, but I didn't do anything specific, should I have asked my English teacher or something?

Comment: @ab123: My comment was meant to help you find the right answer quicker. Turns out you were satisfied with something quick enough.

Comment: Among other things, you gave us no context.  You can't expect everyone to look up the lyrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Refer to me as* an amenity.
The voice is asking you to think of her as an *amenity* - a useful feature.